# How to convert a shapefile to a complete list of latitude and longitude points

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I'm trying to convert a shapefile to a list of latitude and longitude points that represent every point defined by the shapefile. Reading the file with `geopandas` and using the `.plot()` function displays these points as a graph, but I would like the raw points. I attempted to iterate through the polygons in `geopandas` `.geometry` and store all the points within the polygons. I plotted these points to test if they gave an accurate representation of the area, but they do not. I did all this with the following code:

```
import re
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def geoToList(geodataframe):
    points = []
    for s in geodataframe.geometry:iq
        s = str(s)
        s = re.sub('[^0-9., ]+', '', s).split(',')
        s = map(lambda x: x.strip(), s)
        s = map(lambda x: (float(x.split()[0]), float(x.split()[1])), s)
        points.extend(list(s))   
    return points

habitat = gpd.read_file('desktop/species_19377/species_19377.shp')
#borough = borough.to_crs(epsg=4326)

points = geoToList(habitat)
x = [point[0] for point in points]
y = [point[1] for point in points]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show() #representation of the points in all polygons
habitat.plot() #representtation of the points I want
```

I would like some function that returns a list of points that could be plotted and look identical to the output of `habitat.plot()`

My next idea is to store the graphs as images and assign the pixel values latitude and longitude values based on the scale of the graph, but I'm sure this is more complicated than it needs to be.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all points from a set of Polygons / MultiPolygons, you could do something like this:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon

def points_from_polygons(polygons):
    points = []
    for mpoly in polygons:
        if isinstance(mpoly, MultiPolygon):
            polys = list(mpoly)
        else:
            polys = [mpoly]
        for polygon in polys:
            for point in polygon.exterior.coords:
                points.append(point)
            for interior in polygon.interiors:
                for point in interior.coords:
                    points.append(point)
    return points

points = points_from_polygons(habitat.geometry)
x = [point.x for point in points]
y = [point.y for point in points]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The first solution gives me a value error: x attribute access only provided for Point geometries. The second gives me an attribute error: Polygon object has not attribute x. I have version 0.3.0. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, I somehow assumed the geometries you got were points. Updated the answer

Comment: I've been playing around with this solution and it seems to generate an output very similar to that of the function I posted above, which gives some of the points that define the exterior, but none which define the interior. I could certainly use this to get the interior points, but the solution I have in mind would be messy and computationally expensive. Is there an easier way to get all the points within the shape?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to add a comment that this didn't process the interior, but that it is easy to add that as well. See the updated function to also iterate over the interiors